# How to get network responses from a list of endpoints/APIs using zip operator?

Tags: network-programming, reactive-programming, rx-java, observable

I want to do network requests form a list of endpoints/APIs (not an specific number), then `zip` the responses into a single data point.

I know the `zip` operator has the `FuncN` as `combineFunction`, but I dont want to do the following because I dont know how many APIs are in the list:

```
List<API> apis = ...;
Observable.zip(apis.get(0).search("a"), apis.get(1).search("b"), new Func2<Item, Item, List<Item>>() {
...
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [function you mention](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#zip%28java.lang.Iterable,%20rx.functions.FuncN%29) is exactly what you need, it does not require the number of APIs upfront. You do want to use observables to delay the `search` on the API:

```
List<API> apis = ...;
Observable<API> apisObs = Observable.from(apis);
List<String> args = ... // list of "a", "b" ordered like the apis' list
Observable<String> argsObs = Observable.from(args);
```

Zip the delayed API calls (delaying with `Observable.just`):

```
Observable<ResultType> results = apisObs.zipWith(
    args, (api, arg) -> Observable.just(api.search(arg))
);
```

Now zip again to wait for completion of all delayed calls created:

```
Observable.zip(results, new FuncN<ResultType> ...)
```